# TSQL Select issue returning either too many or way too few rows. Might need a union or similar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is a select that works nicely as is however I have been asked to add in another column and it has me stumped.

I need to add the department name from dbo.DEPARTMENTS.NAME coming from a join to dbo.MOBILEUSER.USER_ID to dbo.MOBILEUSERDEPTS.USER_ID giving DEPT_ID, which joins to DEPARTMENTS on DEPT_ID allowing the select of the DEPARTMENT NAME for the Mobile user. The other issue is that whilst every row has a Employee USER_ID, not every row has a MOBILE USER nor DESKTOP user. Also EMPLOYEES and MOBILE USERS may have multiple DEPARTMENTS and therefore multiple rows. 
Desired Output is
Employee    Employee Employee  EMPDEPT        USER        USER          PORTALUSER PORTALUSER   Mobile
EMPLOYEES on EMP_ID                                     PORTALUSER on USER_ID
EMPDEPTS on DEPT_ID                                     PORTALUSERDEPTS on DEPT_ID
DEPARTMENTS                                         DEPARTMENTS
Department  LastName FirstName EmployeeStatus DesktopUser DesktopStatus PortalUser PortalStatus Department 
Sample
Spokane     Doe     John    Active        NULL     NULL         JDOE       Active   Seattle
London      Smythe  David   Active        David.Smythe Active   DSMYTHE    InActive Oxford
Oxford      Smythe  David   Active        NULL     NULL     NULL       NULL     NULL

Source Table Structure
EMPLOYEES   EMP_ID
        LastName
        FirstName
EMPDEPT     EMP_ID
        DEPT_ID
        Status      Status T/A (Terminated/Active)
DEPARTMENTS DEPT_ID
        Name
USER        USER_ID
        Username
        ACTIVE      Status T/F
PORTALUSER      USER_ID
        LastName
        FirstName
        Username
        Approved    Status T/F
PORTALUSERDEPTS USER_ID
        DEPT_ID

The problem I have is the Mobile User Department  and the Employee Department - I can only get one or the other so far.
    [image]SELECT
        dbo.DEPARTMENTS.NAME as Department, dbo.STAFF.LASTNAME AS Employee, 
        StaffStatus = CASE dbo.STFDEPT.STATUS 
                         WHEN 'T' then 'Terminated'
                         WHEN 'A' then 'Active'
                         ELSE 'WARNING!!'
                      END, 
        dbo.USERS.USERNAME AS Desktop, 
        DeskTopStatus = CASE dbo.USERS.ACTIVE
                           WHEN 'T' then 'Active'
                           WHEN 'F' then 'Inactive'
                           ELSE ''
                        END,
        dbo.MOBILEUSERS.USERNAME AS MOBUser, 
        MobileStatus = CASE dbo.PORTALUSERS.APPROVED
                          WHEN 'T' then 'Active'
                          WHEN 'F' then 'Inactive'
                          ELSE ''
                       END
    FROM
        dbo.STAFF 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.STFDEPT ON dbo.STAFF.EMP_ID = dbo.STFDEPT.EMP_ID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.DEPARTMENTS ON dbo.STFDEPT.DEPT_ID = dbo.DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.USERS ON dbo.DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID = dbo.USERS.DEFDEPT 
                  AND dbo.STAFF.EMP_ID = dbo.USERS.USER_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.PORTALUSERS ON dbo.STAFF.EMAILADDR = dbo.PORTALUSERS.EMAIL
    WHERE
        dbo.STAFF.LASTNAME NOT LIKE 'STAFF%'
        AND dbo.STAFF.LASTNAME NOT LIKE 'Admin%'
    ORDER BY
        2,1

```
SELECT        
    DEPARTMENTS_1.NAME AS Department, 
    dbo.EMPLOYEES.LASTNAME AS Employee, 
    CASE dbo.EMPLDEPT.STATUS 
       WHEN 'T' THEN 'Terminated' 
       WHEN 'A' THEN 'Active' 
       ELSE 'WARNING!!' 
    END AS EmployeeStatus, 
    dbo.USERS.USERNAME AS Desktop, 
    CASE dbo.USERS.ACTIVE 
       WHEN 'T' THEN 'Active' 
       WHEN 'F' THEN 'Inactive' 
       ELSE '' 
    END AS DeskTopStatus, 
    dbo.PORTALUSERS.USERNAME AS PortUser, 
    CASE dbo.PORTALUSERS.APPROVED 
       WHEN 'T' THEN 'Active' 
       WHEN 'F' THEN 'Inactive' 
       ELSE '' 
    END AS MobileStatus
FROM
    dbo.EMPLOYEES 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.EMPLDEPT ON dbo.EMPLOYEES.EMP_ID = dbo.EMPLDEPT.EMP_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.DEPARTMENTS ON dbo.EMPLDEPT.DEPT_ID = dbo.DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PORTALUSERDEPTS ON dbo.DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID = dbo.PORTALUSERDEPTS.DEPT_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.PORTALUSERS ON dbo.PORTALUSERDEPTS.USER_ID = dbo.PORTALUSERS.USER_ID 
                    AND dbo.EMPLOYEES.EMAILADDR = dbo.PORTALUSERS.EMAIL 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.DEPARTMENTS AS DEPARTMENTS_1 ON dbo.PORTALUSERDEPTS.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENTS_1.DEPT_ID 
                                     AND dbo.EMPLDEPT.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENTS_1.DEPT_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.USERS ON dbo.DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID = dbo.USERS.DEFDEPT 
              AND dbo.EMPLOYEES.EMP_ID = dbo.USERS.USER_ID 
              AND DEPARTMENTS_1.DEPT_ID = dbo.USERS.DEFDEPT
WHERE        
    (dbo.EMPLOYEES.LASTNAME NOT LIKE '99%') 
    AND (dbo.EMPLOYEES.LASTNAME NOT LIKE 'Contractor%')
ORDER BY 
    Employee, Department
```

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from adding another column to the `SELECT` list?

Comment: Because I am seriously no sql guru, when I added the additional table and therefore the column, I went from the 486 required records to 19. I am trying to reproduce the updated SQL now and will add to the trail soon.

Comment: Hmm...adding another column to the `SELECT` list should not really change the number of records coming back.  I'll keep an eye out for your update.

Comment: Updated select brings out 15000 rows instead of 486. Is it the type of join?

Comment: Here's some general advice: (1) Rewrite your query to not need a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. Except for rare cases, you should only ever need INNER, LEFT or FULL JOIN. (2) Don't order by column ID's, you should name the columns you are sorting on. (3) Use aliases for your tables, and use the aliases to reference column names, this makes the query much more readable.

Comment: Please post your source table structure and desired output.

Comment: Done. Added the table structure and required format with some sample data.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I'm still not clear on your schema. While I can see the tables and their fields, it's not entirely clear to me which fields are primary or foreign keys or the nature of the relationships between records in the tables (1-to-1, 1-to-Many, Many-to-Many). If you still need this answered, perhaps you could include a clear set of example records for each of the tables and your expected output based on that sample data. Then it should be pretty easy for someone to help fix your query.